# Regex - Extract string between characters if they exist

Tags: regex, string, extract, between

I would need to use RegEx to extract a string between characters if they exist (The colon character).

Examples:

- SX: **22AA 001 267**
- **2294 0BB 267**: 09
- **2294 0CC 267**

In all cases, I want the result.

```
2294 001 267
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error you hit? I hope you do not expect here a ready solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/98mw5l/1) regex to match them all

```
(?:^|:)\s?([A-Z\d]+(?: [A-Z\d]+)+)(?:$|:)
```

**NOTE:** As you did not mention what language you're using I decided to not use lookarounds. So you have to get the first group from the match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
I just omitted to say that the code can be alphanumeric.

SX: 22AA 001 267
2294 0BB 267: 09
2294 0CC 267

Results
22AA 001 267
2294 0BB 267
2294 0CC 267

Comment: Then try [`(?:^|:)\s?([A-Z\d]+(?: [A-Z\d]+)+)(?:$|:)`](https://regex101.com/r/98mw5l/1)